# MongoDB - slow query on old documents (aggregation and sorting)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have two DBs for testing and each contains thousands/hundreds of thousand of documents.
But with the same Schemas and CRUD operations.

Let's call DB1 and DB2.

I am using Mongoose
Suddenly DB1 became really slow during:

```js
const eventQueryPipeline = [
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [{ userId: req.body.userId }, { serverId: req.body.serverId }],
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sort: -1,
    },
  },
];

const aggregation = db.collection
  .aggregate(eventQueryPipeline)
  .allowDiskUse(true);
aggregation.exect((err, result) => {
  res.json(result);
});
```

In DB2 the same exact query runs in milliseconds up to maximum a 10 seconds
In DB1 the query never takes less than 40 seconds.

I do not understand why. What could I be missing?
I tried to confront the Documents and the Indexes and they're the same.
Deleting the collection and restrting saving the documents, brings the speed back to normal and acceptable, but why is it happening? Does someone had same experience?

Comment: Where are your indexes created? What is the explain plan?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid the only index that is getting created is the _id that mongo creates automatically and there is no $explain. it is not a backend that I built. I barely know mongo, I'm a frontender trying to investigate on a backend problem lol

Comment: Without an index on `{userId: 1, serverId: 1}` the issue is quite obvious.

Comment: It didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You should create following index:

```
{ "userId": 1, "serverId": 1, "sort": 1 }
```

**Longer answer**

Based on your code (i see that you have `.allowDiskUse(true)`) it looks like mongo is trying to do in memory sort with "a lot" of data. Mongo has by default 100MB system memory limit for sort operations, and you can allow it to use temporary files on disk to store data if it hits that limit.
You can read more about it here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.allowDiskUse/

In order to optimise the performance of your queries, you can use indexes.
Common rule that you should follow when planning indexes is ESR (Equality, Sort, Range). You can read more about it here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/tutorial/equality-sort-range-rule/

If we follow that rule while creating our compound index, we will add equality matches first, in your case **"userId"** and **"serverId"**. After that comes the sort field, in your case **"sort"**.

If you had a need to additionally filter results based on some range (eg. some value greater than X, or timestamp greater than yday), you would add that after the "sort".

That means your index should look like this:

```
schema.index({ userId: 1, serverId: 1, sort: 1 });
```

Additionally, you can probably remove allowDiskUse, and handle err inside aggregation.exec callback (im assuming that `aggregation.exect` is a typo)

Comment: It worked! It is still slow (around 10 seconds) but the benchmark was at 40s so it is a huge improvement. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you exec: `db.collection.find({ userId: req.body.userId, serverId: req.body.serverId }).sort({ sort: -1 }).explain('executionStats')` and give us results of executionStats. It should contain info like nReturned, executionTimeMillis, totalKeysExamined, totalDocsExamined. Thnx @thomscoder

Comment: executionSuccess: true,
     nReturned: 2997,
     executionTimeMillis: 296,
     totalKeysExamined: 143919,
     totalDocsExamined: 143919,
    inputStage: 
         { stage: 'IXSCAN',
           nReturned: 143919,
           executionTimeMillisEstimate: 32,
           works: 143920,
           advanced: 143919,
           needTime: 0,
           needYield: 0,
           saveState: 152,
           restoreState: 152,
           isEOF: 1,
           keyPattern: { sort: 1 },
           indexName: 'sort',
 etc...

In mongo shell works like a charm. Via mongoose it gets slower.

Comment: That query executes really fast , but if I take away the .explain() it becomes slow as snail :-|

Comment: Based on what i see, it looks like mongo is using index `{ sort: 1 }`.
Its faster than before, but mongo still needs to get examine 143919 docs before returning only 2997. You want to make sure that your query uses `{ userId: 1, serverId: 1, sort: 1}`. Can you run this in mongo shell: `db.collection.getIndexes()` and post results?

Comment: [
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  { v: 2, key: { userId: 1 }, name: 'userId', background: false },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { serverId: 1 },
    name: 'serverId',
    background: false
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { sort: 1 },
    name: 'sort',
    background: false
  }
]

Mongo Comapss tells me indexes usage are all 0, but that's the result of getIndexes(). It happens only with this DB . The speed of same query on another DB with same amount of documents pulverizes this one.

Comment: As expected, you didnt create a "compound index". You should run this in your mongo shell to create your compound index: `db.collection.createIndex({ userId: 1, serverId: 1, sort: 1 })`. You want to create an index with all 3 fields in this particular oder, and not 3 separate indexes for each field.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the compound index, but it is still not working. I think I'll open a issue on MongoDB forum. Thanks for the help by the way